# Wilcoxon signed-rank test for paired and repeated measures data

Tags: repeated-measures, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank, validity

I have a dataset with 45 participants, each with 1-7 datapoints/observations (126 total observations). Each of these observations represents a window of time in which two different methods attempt to classify how much time is spent in an activity. I would like to compare the amount of time each method predicts for each observation to determine if the two methods are equivalent.

From what I have read the paired comparison aspect is an excellent use of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test (especially since they are non-parametric). My question is whether this is still the best test with the unequal repeated measures component.

Comment: Wilcon signed rank test would ignore the repeated measures nature of your data.

Comment: If you want to see if the two methods are similar, then you wouldn't you want, say, plot the paired points (Method1, Method2), and see if the results track to a 1:1 line?  Also, you might look at a [Bland-Altman plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot), which is used to compare the results of two analytical methods.